# Meaning of "rubber" as a verb in O. Henry

Tags: meaning, short-stories, o-henry

> "I'm one of the Sole Sanhedrims and Ostensible Hooplas of the Inner Pulpit," says I. "**The lame talk and the blind rubber** whenever I make a pass at 'em. I am a medium, a coloratura hypnotist and a spirituous control."
> <sub>-- [O. Henry, "Jeff Peters as a Personal Magnet"](https://americanliterature.com/author/o-henry/short-story/jeff-peters-as-a-personal-magnet)</sub>

It appears that the word *rubber* is used as a verb in this sentence. And, as far as I know, in this context it is intended to mean "to [regain the ability to] move/walk/limp/etc." and so on. But searching through the online dictionaries I have not been able to find a fitting definition for the verb *to rubber*.

Is this some kind of beginning-of-the-century American slang that never made it into "official" dictionaries? Or am I misinterpreting its usage?

Comment: It is beginning-of-the-century slang, in fact. Rubber vulcanization was a late development. At the time O. Henry wrote, stretchy rubber was a novelty, especially in the rural settings of most of his stories.

Comment: It's not clear that "rubber" is being used as a verb.  "Talk" isn't, in the above quote.

Comment: And the term "rubber" originally meant "scrubber" or "eraser", and only began to acquire it's current meaning in the mid 1800s.

Comment: @Hot Licks: What made conclude that "talk" is not a verb in the quote?

Comment: Because "talk" in that context is a noun.  Consider that "lame" is an adjective, not an adverb.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Well, formally yes, but not really. The intended meaning of this sentence is "The lame [begin to] talk and the blind [begin to] rubber whenever I make a pass at 'em". "The lame" refers to people who limp, "the blind" refers to blind people. The phrase is deliberately crafted to include the obvious mismatch between the malady and the "healing effect" (e.g. "the lame [begin to] talk") is intentional. It is intended to be humorous from the reader's point of view (and supposed to convey condescending attitude of the fraudster towards its victims in the book's universe).

Comment: @HotLicks But there is certainly room for an adverb. The lame (people) (incessantly) talk.

Comment: @PhilSweet - It might make sense if it were "the lame *walk* and the blind rubber".

Comment: @Hot Licks: Yes, but the protagonist does not intend to *make sense*. On the contrary, the fraudster actually uses the opportunity to have some fun at his victims' expense (who are supposedly not very bright). That's the whole humorous idea behind this wording. He *negligently* or, more likely, *intentionally* says "the lame talk" instead of the "the lame walk". He knows that the audience is too mesmerized by his charms to notice the error.

Comment: I agree, the balderdash works with the meaning of rubbernecking. What would the blind be rubbernecking for?.

Comment: @Phil Sweet: That would kinda partially defeat the humor behind of the phrase. The idea is that the healing effect should *not* match the malady it is linked to.

Comment: I will note that a [Russian translation](https://tgraph.io/O-Henry-Jeff-Peters-As-A-Personal-Magnet-610-01-20) of the piece appears to interpret it (per Google Translate) as "the lame / begin / speak, and the blind - to hear, if I just make a pass in their direction"

Comment: @Hot Licks: Yes, this is where I got my original theory about the supposedly "intended" meaning of *rubber*. However, the Russian translation of the second part of the sentence ("... whenever I make a pass at 'em") is not entirely accurate, even though the translated version also works perfectly well in the context. It is quite possible that *rubber* was also translated rather loosely.

Comment: Yeah, the definition of "rubber" was quite stretchy in the era when O Henry was writing.  It is plausible that the "eavesdropping" meaning proposed by @frathoss is correct.

Comment: @AnT "The protagonist does not intend to make sense." If that's the case, then why are you trying to impose rules of grammar on the sentence? I don't think it's supposed to be a verb. As far as I can tell, *lame talk* is a noun phrase—in just the same way that *blind rubber* is a noun phrase. (Although they both slyly hint at being verbs.) It's a deliberate play on words, resulting in something ungrammatical but which still makes sense. Consider it a meta pun.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: I think I have already provided a rather detailed explanation in what specific sense he "does not intend to make sense". My previous statements were made in context. No need to take them out of context and stretch to the point of absurdity. And no, "lame talk" and "blind rubber" are not noun phrases in this case.

Comment: @AnT How do you *know* that "lame talk" and "blind rubber" are not noun phrases? They certainly sound like noun phrases to me. As I said, I believe the very point of the wordplay is that they *are* noun phrases—but that they are being used in a way that makes them suggestive of verbs (even though they aren't). But, at best, the syntax is ambiguous and open to interpretation.

Answer (score 6):

**The entire phrase is a nonsensical piece of wordplay**

"The lame walk and the blind see" is a well known biblical phrase, said by Jesus to indicate his holiness. The phrase is corrupted here into nonsense, in keeping with the nonsense religious position he claims immediately before it, and the nonsense powers he claims after it.

"The lame talk" makes no sense as a sign of holiness, and "lame talk" is a well known (noun) phrase meaning idle chatter (probably more so at the time of writing) Likewise "blind rubber" doesn't make sense as a subject-verb pair, but would have been well known as meaning [a rubber seal that closes off a hole](https://www.grommets.co.uk/products/grommets/blind-rubber-grommets/). This is the sort of joke O. Henry was known for. As AnT says, the protagonist of the story frequently makes good-sounding nonsense statements.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say here. The "the lame walk and the blind see" phrase you quoted (and quite appropriately at that) uses *walk* and *see* as *verbs*. The O.Henry's sentence in intended to have the same structure, meaning that *talk* and *rubber* are used as verbs. And yes, everybody understands that there's an obvious mismatch in this sentence. However, the intent of the first part ("the lame talk") is clear. It is nonsensical, but not gibberish. But the second part ("the blind rubber") is not clear. Do you mean that this second part is *intended* to be a complete gibberish?

Comment: Yes, but not appropriate verbs, and in the case of 'rubber' not a real one. Please don't make me explain the joke any more.

Comment: The verb *talk* is indeed not appropriate (it is humorously mismatched *on purpose*), but it comes from the proper general category: a form of recovery from some malady. I assume that the verb *rubber* was chosen in accordance with the same principle: humorously mismatched, but still from the proper general category (also recovery from another malady). Was it not?

Comment: If I may suggest a modern equivalent "This music video will make your ear bud and your eye pod."

Answer (score 5):

While both of the existing answers touch on relevant matters I believe they both miss the mark in terms of the intended meaning.

@frathoss cites a range of definitions including one which supports the OED definition of 'rubber' as

> North American colloquial. To listen (in) on a party telephone line, or on any telephone conversation.

but declares the relevant meaning not to be that one.

@DJClayworth reminds us of the biblical phrase 'the blind see, the lame walk, those with skin diseases are healed, the deaf hear, the dead are raised, and the poor are told the good news' to which the phrases in the short story allude. However, I think reference to 'lame talk' and 'blind rubbers' as noun-phrases is a red herring. Search results for 'blind rubber' mostly lead to 'blind rubber grommets' where rubber is an adjective rather than a noun. Google Books hits for 'lame talk' between 1914 and 1973 primarily brings up either false positives where 'lame' and 'talk' are separated by punctuation, or the O Henry story. Other uses do occur, but they are in the minority and generally post date the 1908 publication of *Jeff Peters as a Personal Magnet*.

In the story, Jeff Peters is engaging in bombastic tall-talk as part of his spiel to con the Judge, he is aware as he does this that the Judge believes *himself* to be engaged in a 'con' to bring Jeff Peters to justice. So we can understand the whole bedside performance to be entirely theatrical. Jeff Peters isn't truly trying to sell anything because he knows that the Judge isn't really ill and that the Judge believes himself to be setting Peters up for arrest, and already knows full well that the 'healing through personal magnetism' is fake, just as Peters' bottled medicine is a mere  nostrum.

So the spiel is pure performance, only intended to convince the judge that Peters is unsuspecting, and to leave him something to chew on down the line when the con has become apparent:

> "'Mr. Mayor,' says I, 'the time will come soon when you'll believe that personal magnetism is a success. And you'll be sure that it succeeded in this case, too.'

So Peters is having fun with the words, using phrases that echo the New Testament but don't convey its meaning, the lame can already *talk*, the blind can already *rubber* on their neighbour's telephone conversations. As part of a sales pitch these might be claimed to create plausible deniability that the vendor can't be held responsible for the misunderstandings of his customers. But in this instance he is running a different con and what he has to *sell* is the idea of himself as an over-confident conman who doesn't realise he is in a trap.

So literally 'rubber' means 'listen in on other's conversations on a party line', but its *function* is to contribute to bolstering the Judge's belief that Peters is unaware he is being set up.

Answer (score 1):

Rubber as a verb can hold two meanings.

1. The act of eavesdropping

1999, Los Angeles Times, "Party's Over for Rural Phone Customers in Green Mountain State," (Jan. 31, 1999):
"There's a lot of nostalgia about the phone and how it was the way to get the local news," said Jane Beck of the Vermont Folklife Center in Middlebury. One way was "rubbering," or listening in on a neighbor's conversations

or the more slang:

2. Rubbernecking (Snapping ones neck to look at something so quickly it appears to be made of rubber)

1951, J.D. Salinger, The Catcher in the Rye, Chapter 17:
Old Sally didn't talk much, except to rave about the Lunts, because she was busy rubbering and being charming.

Comment: That's nice but that doesn't answer the question. If you mean that the word "rubber" is used in one of these meanings, then which one? And would you explain the meaning of the original sentence under the definition you suggest?

Comment: Yes, it is using the second definition. "Take a pass" is slang for flirting or making a sexual advance. The last part of the sentence describing himself as a Coloratura, Hypnotist, and spiritual control is referring to his skills at flirting and being charismatic. He is bragging. He is so good at flirting that he makes the lame talk and the blind "Rubber" or snap their necks to take a look. The sentence is expressing irony.

Comment: No, no, no, I don't believe this is even remotely accurate. The protagonist is a small-time fraudster who claims having extraordinary *healing* abilities. He says that he can heal lame (limping) people and blind people. But he treats his prospective "marks" condescendingly, as dimwits. Which is why he doesn't even care to make sense when he speaks to them (or even deliberately mocks them). He says: "The lame [regain the ability to] talk and the blind [regain the ability to] rubber whenever I make [my healing] pass at 'em". That's the intended structure of the original phrase.

Comment: I will admit I am not as knowledgeable of the setting of this story as you seem to be, however even in your example the second definition I explained of rubber is fitting. As your context describes the act of transforming blind people to look in ones direction to look at something that caught the eye.

Comment: Its a wordplay joke.

Comment: @AnT I don't believe that the speaker means to say that he heals the lame and the blind at all. he means people to understand that he has said such *without* saying it.

Comment: @frathoss It’s a very short story and the OP provides a link to it. The usage really repays reading in context.